# Finish parent and current activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities. Activity A which leads to activity B, which in turn can go back to activity A or start activity C. However, if I press back in activity C the app should close.

To sum up:

- Activity A starts activity B
- Pressing **Back** on activity B should lead to A
- Activity B starts activity C
- Pressing **Back** on activity C should close the app

How should I go from activity B to C? This code currently gives me a NullPointerException on the last line:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
ActivityB.this.finish();
ActivityB.this.getParent().finish();
```

If I switch the last two lines I also get a null pointer.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that having the app close after hitting the back button when you're not on the first page of the app is really annoying. I'm not sure what you're doing, but just be careful that the users don't expect that the back button will go to the previous activity

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but you could try it:

- From Activity A, start activity B for a result using `startActivityForResult()`
- In Activity B, when the user triggers Activity C, start activity C.

`startActivity()` returns immediately, so

- set a result that will inform A to finish as well,
- Call `finish()` in B.
- When A receives that result from B, A calls `finish()` on itself as well.

Failing that, you could make Activity C into its own app and then close the first app (with A & B) after it starts the second.

P.S. Take Falmarri's comment into consideration as you move forward!
Good luck.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to finish a parent activity from a child activity,

In the parent activity, while triggering the child activity, use the following command:-

```
startActivityForResult(intent_name,any_integer_variable);
```

and override the onActivityResult Method in the following manner:-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==2){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now, in the child activity, override onStop and onDestroy in the following manner:-

```
protected void onStop() {
    setResult(2);
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    setResult(2);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Notice that I've set the value to 2 in the child activity, and am checking for it in the parent activity. If the value is the same that I have set, then the parent activity will also finish.
Then you can use recursive approaches for further activities.

Comment: I did exactly the same, but no matter what value I set in child activity using `setResult()`, parent activity is always receiving `0`.

Comment: I found that `onActivityResult` gets called before `onStop` and `onDestroy`, you need to `setResult` before.

Comment: How can any_integer_variable be used?

Answer (score 15):

You shou use **onActivityResult** method in your parent Activity

Suppose Activity A is parent of Activity B.
If you want to click back button in Activity B to exit Application (also exit Activity A)

In your Activity B, in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`

you call

```
setResult(0); //any int number is fine
```

this will pass a result code to its parent activity.

Your parent Actvity A, listens for the result code
you will need to use `onActivityResult` method
inside the method you can call

```
if(resultCode == 0) //matches the result code passed from B
{
    ActivityA.this.finish()
}
```

It works for me :)

Comment: Nice solution. setResult with code from child activity and receive resultCode on parent activity. Now I can handle parent activity will also destroy when a specific button click from child activity.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't do any of this. This is how I would revise your code.

the code you use to enter another intent:

```
Intent whatEverIntentName = new Intent("Path.to.next.Intent");
startActivity(whatEverIntentName);
finish();
```

This way, you always quit when pressing back. But wait! You can change how you want your 
back key press to react when pressed.

Do this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent whatEverIntentName = new Intent("Path.to.the.activity.before.it");
    startActivity(whatEverIntentName);
// Don't add finish here. 
//This is necessary because you finished your last activity with finish();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

None of that worked for me. So I found out a solution. The help clearly lists that Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK must be used with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. So here is a code that worked for me.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `finishAffinity()` , it will close Current & all Parent Activities of the Current Activity.

Note : But any results from Child Activity to Parent Activity will not be handled.

Hope, it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is there any drawback in using same .. ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on Activity A and started another activity called Activity B.
Activity A --> Activity B

And now want to close both activities.

then use the below code in Activity B.

```
B.this.finish();
```

And use this code in Activity A:

```
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
finish();
```

As soon as activity B will finish, Activity A will also finish.

There is one drawback, I do not know may be you want this or not.

Drawback is that If user is on Activity B and s/he press back button to move on the Activity A. Then, Activity A will also finish in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfectly:

```
btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v) {

Player.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

your activity C will the root activity and on press back will finish the apps.

Answer (score 1):

From the screen(B) you want to start the screen(C) with NO back screen, just
start this screen (C) with:

```
screenC.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP 
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(screenC);
finish();
```

The back in screenC will exit the application.

Answer (score 1):

From Activity A, start activity B for a result using startActivityForResult(intent,19)

In Activity B, when the user triggers Activity C, start activity C.

startActivity() returns immediately, so

set a result that will inform A to finish as well,

Call finish() in B.
and Call setResult() method before finish() method in your Child Activity
In Parent Activity overide onActivtyResult(....) method.
When A receives that result from B, A calls finish() on itself as well.

```
enter code here
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    //Added by Ashish to close parent activity
      if(arg1==19){
      finish();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have each activity listen for a result from the next activity, and finish itself if that occurs.

You can use a special result code to indicate that you want the activity to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the [**back key behavior**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29):

> Activity A starts activity B
>   Pressing Back on activity B should lead to A
>   Activity B starts activity C
>   Pressing Back on activity C should close the app

Note that I don't call super from onBackPressed.
This also allows you to override the browse stack mechanism for Android, which I find to be a big advantage, since currently there doesn't seem to be a way to clear the single oldest item from the browse stack in a simple way.

```
public class B extends Activity
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // Start activity A
        Intent aIntent = new Intent(this, A);
        startActivity(bIntent);
    }
    ...
}

public class C extends Activity
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // Close
        finish();
    }
    ...
}
```

You can specifically finish the parent activity if needed too, but using this method, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do it for you. Almost in all other approaches your app will remain in recent apps. Javadoc can be found at, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html#finishAndRemoveTask()

```
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(am != null) {
                List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
                if (tasks != null) {
                    tasks.get(0).finishAndRemoveTask();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of ActivityB.

on ActivityB.java

```
public static ActivityB instanceOfActivityB;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instanceOfActivityB = this;
}
```

on ActivityC.java

```
void onClose() {
   ActivityB.instanceOfActivityB.finish();
   finish();
}
```

Hope it helps!