# How to close parent activity within child activity?

Tags: android

How do I close a parent activity from a child activity?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android)

Comment: MisterS, your link is broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You **cant** finish a parent `Activity` from child directly, as child is itself running from Parent

Comment: @MisterSquonk But there are parent and child activities in android, you can refer to `TabActivity` to see this. Though this isn't the common case.

Comment: If only you were right! Just now my daughter activity while finishing somehow orders the parent to finish, too!. And I don't know how she does it and how to stop it.