# Android: Override back button

Tags: android

I have a Main Activity, then a ListActivity to select an item to show, and then a third activity to show selected item. When user push back button, I want him to go back to main activity, not the listActivity.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Probably the simplest is to call

```
finish();
```

in the ListActivity immediately after you call `startActivity` to start the third activity.

This will achieve what you want with no overriding of the back button required.

Comment: agreed. The whole question is to know if, it your conception, it is your list that is not supposed to appear again, or your item that is supposed to take you all the way back.

Answer (score 3):

override onBack in 3rd activity and use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the intent flags which you use when creating your new activity such as [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK), and others like it.

Also, this other question may be of help: [Finish parent and current activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android/3410781#3410781)

Answer (score 0):

in your back button you can start the main Activity using intents

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Main.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(i);
```

why setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed
>   and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onKeyDown`.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                 // start your main Activity  with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                return true;
            }


        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

`onBackPressed()` is only supported by latest versions of the API.