# Finish activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have program with login, main activity and other activities.
First step is login activity(A). If login succeed start main activity(B) and call finish for (A).
working with (B) I'm calling some activities and then back to (B).
When decide to exit - I call logout and try to close (B) calling finish.
This logik works in 70% ot time :(
Unfortunately on 30% after calling finish for (B) - activity(A) appears on screen and start logging me.

Who is starting (B) again? I din't see relation between problem and program usage.

Update:
I put hohistory for (B) and start (B) with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

UPDATE2: Described behaviour is typical when I set screen orientation mode in code. In manifest  is set portrait. When start activity I'm setting orientation depending on user config. This produced onCreaste twice. I got managed to handle this properly, but this causes problem as described. If I don't set orientation - one onCreate is called and no problem with finish.

Comment: in your last sentence did you mean (A) instead of (B)? Also it will be nearly impossible for us to help you at all if you do not include the relavent source code from your activities.

Comment: could you include the code of the intent in A after log in and the code that log out and finish the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setScreenOrientation made thinks complicated.
It is not enought to set noHistory for activityA and call activityB with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

When Start app in portrait mode /as declared in manifest/ - It was OK.
But when call setScreenOrientation - have to call finishB 2 times to exit.
/Probably because ot 2 times onCreate for activityB/.

### This made thinks to work:

For activityA: android:noHistory="true" and android:launchMode="singleInstance" in manifest.
Start activityB with startActivityForResult and flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

In activityA:
1. startActivityForResult(activityB)
2. finishA.

In activityB - when call finish() for B - because of 'singleinstance' system din't start activityA again.

Hope this help.
If anybody know reason which will cause error - please write me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this when you logout in `activity` B. The activity displays the home screen.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following links, you will get the solution:

[Finish parent and current activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear).You

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting your application from an IDE (like eclipse), or from the app installer? If so, you will see this situation if you do the following.

- Launch your application from the IDE or after installation from the installer (displays your first activity)
- press the HOME key (takes you back to home screen)
- launch your application again by selecting it from the list of available applications

This sequence will create 2 copies of your first activity, one on top of the other. When you finish the top one, the one underneath it will be shown.

You say this doesn't happen all the time. If you don't launch the app from the IDE, but just from the list of available applications you won't see this behaviour. Also, if you never press the HOME key and relaunch the app using the list of available applications you won't see this behaviour either.

Comment: Good point of view. Actually this happens in boot cases: from Eclipse and when started from phone. Is there a way to control that?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But there is a workaround you can use to prevent the creation of the second instance of the activity. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373#c21

Answer (score 0):

When you go from activity A to activity B first time you are supposed to clear your stack top. Otherwise activity A stays in the stack below B and when u finish B, activity B is called again.

Comment: I understand this. But why this not happens every time? This is strange for me and I'm trying to understand before go trouhg this.

Comment: you mean that your app closes even while activity A still remains in the stack?
a little of your code would really help.

Answer (score 0):

you should set in manifest file `android:noHistory="true"` to make your A activity not to stay on android stack.

In case you would like to do it from code in future by using intents  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` will do the job for you.. Cheers