# control the previous button and lifecycleofapp

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have some problems with controlling the previous button and lifecycle of app, this is scheme of my application, I try to describe my knowledge about it.

[image]

I can move between categories without any limitation. For example, I run my app the `firts screen` which is named `third category` then I move to `second category` and then to `third one`. When I click the previous button It moves me to `second category`, because this was the previous screen, but I want that "physical previous button" exit from whole application, no matter what I made before, so it should switch every existing activity to onStop and onDestroy or how should be done?

I try to destroy previous category activity when I move to next one,by `finish();` but I addedto onDestroy some methods which clears list, so during lifetime of application it's not desired thing.

Comment: use finish(); when you are moving from one activity to other

Comment: finish() = onDestroy() imo, and I've some clearing methods there, so I don't want make it during app lifetime, when I tried it I cleared my list every time when I move to other category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code inside `onBackPressed()`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

[Other Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android/13539381#13539381) may help you.

Comment: I think it's work excellent ;) It's flag this activity like home so everything what was previous is cleared? This is the way it works?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the **onDestroy();** right after the intent you use to call the next category/next activity.