# Finish activity that is waiting for result

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing the login system and currently the flow is as follows:

LoginActivity can call ExecuteLoginActivity to show a screen with a progressbar while it connects to the backend via an AsyncTask to authenticate the user and return the result to the LoginActivity, which can then call the MainActivity, or the LoginActivity can call the SignUpActivity that can then call the ExecuteSignUpActivity which does the same as the ExecuteLoginActivity but for signup, and then return the result to the SignUpActivity that in turn returns the result to the LoginActivity which can then call the MainActivity.

The problem with this approach is that the LoginScreen (and sometimes the SignUpActivity) ends up "flashing" to the user before it can call the MainActivity. I want the Execute activities to call the MainActivity themselves after a sucessfull login/signup and to return to the Login/Signup activities to show an error on a failed attempt.

I tought about using a broadcast to send a signal to finish the Login/Signup activities on a sucessfull login but I don't know if I can finish them while they are waiting for the result of the spawned Execute activities. So my question is, can I finish an activity that is waiting for the result of another activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theoric question was not directly answered, but I found a solution to the pratictal problem in the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android).

Basically, what I did was calling startActivity() to start the MainActivity directly, and then return success and finishing all the other activities on their respective OnActivityResult() methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Sign up and Login Activity do this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Comment: This looks really good, but do you know if there is a problem because of the activities waiting for a result? Doesn't the OS hold a reference for the activity waiting the result?