# Can't finish singleTask activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities: **A**, **B**, **C**. **A** is a `singleTask` activity. I need to start activity **B** from activity **A**. And then I need to start **A** from **C**. But the problem is when I am trying to start **A** from **C**, **A's** `onCreate` not being called. I tried also to use `onNewIntent` but it also not being called. Is there any way to finish an old **A** and start a new activity **A** from activity **C**?

Comment: Call finish() in Activity A just after you start Activity B. when C calls A, it will call onCreate() again (because A has already finished)

Comment: I can't do that because in some cases user can go back from B to A so it should remain alive.

Comment: are you sure its not calling on onNewIntent? it must have to call.

Comment: you can try this. basically, you create a startActivityForResult() when launching Activity B. when B creates C, then return with a result to tell Activity A to finish itself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410781/908821

Comment: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959 read this post. it can help you.

Comment: use fragments...

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Yeah, 100% sure, tested several times